# Git 'remote-https' not being installed when building source

Tags: linux, git, curl, centos7

I am trying to install git from source on a server running `CentOS Linux 7.7.1908` that I do NOT have root permissions on.

I have used Conda before to install Git and some other tools because it doesn't require root access, but it is not a clean solution and I have to deactivate the environment several times for using certain programs. So I am trying to install things from source to my ~/.local tree as a learning exercise and for convenience.

After installing from source to my user directory, I can use the git executable to clone SSH remotes but not HTTPS. Here is an example of the problem:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/test/test.git ~/tmp/test_repo
Cloning into '/home/group/user/tmp/test_repo'...
git: 'remote-https' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

The problem seems to be caused by the Git build system not recognizing curl/libcurl on my system.

The solution for most people is to use a package manager to install libcurl-devel, or similar. I cannot do this.

I do have curl installed, whatever came with this build of CentOS I assume:

```
$ curl -V
curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0 NSS/3.44 zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.8.0
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz unix-sockets
```

I also have tried installing openSSL and curl from source in my user directory, but I get the same results after trying to build Git:

```
$ curl -V
curl 7.85.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.85.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1q zlib/1.2.7
Release-Date: 2022-08-31
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS HSTS HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

My Git installation steps are as follows:

```
$ make configure
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/tmp/git_test
$ make all -j
$ make install
```

After running the newly generated binary, I get the same results:

```
$ ./bin/git clone https://github.com/test/test.git ~/tmp/clone_test
Cloning into '/home/user/tmp/clone_test'...
git: 'remote-https' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

I assume the problem is related to my libcurl installation, but I just don't know where the connection is messed up!

EDIT: I tried installing libcurl-devel by extracting an RPM binary package. Now I have the following directory structure:

```
├── bin
│   └── curl-config
├── include
│   └── curl
│       ├── curlbuild-64.h
│       ├── curlbuild.h
│       ├── curl.h
│       ├── curlrules.h
│       ├── curlver.h
│       ├── easy.h
│       ├── mprintf.h
│       ├── multi.h
│       ├── stdcheaders.h
│       └── typecheck-gcc.h
├── lib64
│   ├── libcurl.so -> libcurl.so.4.3.0
│   ├── libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.3.0
│   ├── libcurl.so.4.3.0
│   └── pkgconfig
│       └── libcurl.pc
└── share
    ├── aclocal
    │   └── libcurl.m4
    ├── doc
    │   └── libcurl-devel-7.29.0
    └── man
        ├── man1
        └── man3
```

To solve my problem, I need to know the mechanism in which Git's configure/make tools detect if a system has libcurl installed.

Comment: Instead of plain curl -- You need to install `libcurl` -- Very common `git` mistake ..  See [This Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/694507/git-clone-from-https-url-fails-says-its-remote-https-is-not-a-git-command-an#:~:text=This%20error%20occurs%20if%20you,It%20should%20work.)

Comment: @Zak I believe libcurl was installed when I installed curl, as you can see from the output of `curl -V`. Also, I have several libcurl .a, .la, .so, .so.4 files in my local lib folder.

Is there a way to install the "-devel" version of libcurl from source?

Comment: when you issue `$ curl-config` does it give versioning info?  Also make sure you have `libcurl-devel` installed ..

Comment: `remote-https` is a part of libcurl explicitly .. So your system "thinks" libcurl isn't there ..

Comment: I added an edit to my post, after attempting to install libcurl-devel. I'm just not sure how the build tools check if libcurl-devel is installed, so that I can properly install it...

Comment: Here. this worked for me..

`apt update && apt install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev libpcre2-dev libssl-dev zlib1g && make configure && ./configure && make git-remote-https git`

Also, search the Makefile for `optional library` and you will find some more.

Also also, check the INSTALL file in the git/git repo for further info.

Comment: I just ran into this on Debian 11. I ended up having to `apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev`; the other libcurl was already installed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `--with-curl`, `--with-openssl`, and possibly `--with-expat`

```bash
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/tmp/git_test --with-curl=/curl/install/prefix ... etc.
```